# Replace content with regex

Tags: regex, robotframework

For robotframework **Replace String Using Regexp**, I need to write a regex but I'm newbie can you help me ?

Need to transform in a String each occurs
like `{{string1.string2.string3.string4}}`
to   `${string1_string2_string3_string4}`

So the transformations are :

```
{{ will be ${

}} will be }

.  will be _
```

For example I got a string (or a file..) that contain ;

```
{
"my.value_1{}":{{string1.string2.string3.string4}},
"my_value2.}{":{{string1.string2.string3.string4}},
"my_value3":{{string1.string2}}10.64
}
```

I want it to be :

```
{
"my.value_1{}":${string1_string2_string3_string4},
"my_value2.}{":${string1_string2_string3_string4},
"my_value3":${string1_string2}10.64
}
```

As you can see, only occurs that in format {{string1.string2.string3.string4}}
or {{string1.string2}}... must to be transformed by the regex. Chars like { } . must not be transformed if not like format that I said.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I very new in regexp so what I want is to do something like : 
Initial text : {{%.%}}
Final text  : ${%_%}

I got many many occurence like this in a file

Comment: Please edit your question and add your trials there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it with Python that I'm calling in my robotframework !

```
import re

def Reformat_Variables(arg1):
variables = re.findall(r'{{*.*}}', arg1)

for variable in variables:
    formattedVariable = variable.replace('{{', '${')
    formattedVariable = formattedVariable.replace('}}', '}')
    formattedVariable = formattedVariable.replace('.', '_')

    arg1 = arg1.replace(variable, formattedVariable)

return arg1
```

Answer (score 0):

You example is not very clear, please be more concrete with your example next time.

---

I assume this is your initial string:

```
{{string1.string2.string3.string4}}
```

and this is a desired outcome:

```
${string1_string2_string3_string4}
```

You can achieve that in a few steps:

```
Substitute
    ${variable}=    Set Variable    {{string1.string2.string3.string4}}    
    ${variable}=    Replace String Using Regexp    ${variable}    [.]    _
    ${variable}=    Replace String Using Regexp    ${variable}    [{]{2}    {
    ${variable}=    Replace String Using Regexp    ${variable}    [}]{2}    }
    ${variable}=    Set Variable    $${variable}
    Log To Console    ${variable}
```

This will log to console this string:

```
${string1_string2_string3_string4}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not possible to do like this for me because to be more clear I a got a file that containing many text and some variables in this format {{string1.string2.string3.string4}}. I want to apply the regex only on the variables like {{string1.string2.string3.string4}} and not on to others text that may contain { . ) characters..

Comment: I think you need to properly describe your problem with an examples and then someone can help you.

Comment: I edited my initial question to add example and details